# Search Polymorphic relation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using polymorphic relation to store the follower/following information about my users. To get the list of all following users, I use:

```
$following = User::with('following')->findOrFail($id);
```

In `User.php`,

```
public function following()
{
  return $this->morphMany('App\Like', 'user', 'likeable_type')->with('follower');
}
```

Now, I want to search for a particular user in the following users. I tried:

```
$followings = $user->following->where('follower.first_name', 'LIKE', "%$query%");
```

And it's always returning nothing. How can I search for a particular user in this case?

Comment: have you tried putting ->get() or ->first() or exists() after the where statement? that might solve your issue